# Rails Updating Global Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to set a site-wide global variable in my Rails application using the form at the following site:

http://spin360-staging.herokuapp.com/printer

The results should be visible here:

http://spin360-staging.herokuapp.com/printer.json

However, if you refresh the json, you'll see that it doesn't seem persistent - it seems to change values when you refresh the page.

Here's what the form looks like:

```
<%= form_tag edit_printer_path do %>
    <%= label_tag "Type" %>
    <%= select_tag(:type, options_for_select(
        [
            ['Set', "set"],
            ['Spin', "spin"]
            ], 1
        )) %>

<%= label_tag "ID" %>
<%= text_field_tag :print_id %>

<%= label_tag "Format" %>
<%= select_tag(:layout, options_for_select(
    [
        ['Receipt', "receipt"],
        ['Filmstrip', "filmstrip"],
        ['Flipbook', "flipbook"]
        ], 1
    )) %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => "submit_button" %>
```

And the controller method:

```
  def edit_printer
    Rails.application.config.print_type = params[:type]
    Rails.application.config.print_id = params[:print_id]
    Rails.application.config.print_layout = params[:layout]

    redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

And finally, the JSON template (printer.json.erb)

```
{
    "print": [{"type":"<%= Rails.application.config.print_type %>","id":<%= Rails.application.config.print_id %>,"layout": "<%= Rails.application.config.print_layout %>"}] 
}
```

Comment: When I tried it, it worked properly.

Comment: @SophieDéziel try refreshing and you'll see it changes

Comment: it doesn't changes here

Comment: @RonanLopes if I continue to refresh the page, the value changes...

Comment: I think the problem is caused by using heroku. If you are using more than one dyno or when the dyno restarts, the global variable is erased.

For that kind of usage, I would recommend another type of data storage. Redis is a good idea for that case.

Comment: @SophieDéziel I think you are right – I will look into redis.